# Nested if statements in speech AI

Tags: c#, wpf, if-statement

I'm remodeling the infrastructure to my AI, first on using "case" command. Any who i'm trying to change it to become an if statement and then have nested if statements.

All the good as follow.

```
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
        recognizer.LoadGrammar(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Deltagi\Documents\Commands.txt")))));
        GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder();
        builder.AppendDictation();
        grammar = new Grammar(builder);
        recognizer.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(_recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
        recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
        Scot.Volume = 100;
        Scot.Rate = 0;
        Scot.SelectVoice("IVONA Brian");
        MainWebBrowser.IsEnabled = false;
        MainWebBrowser.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

    }

    void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text == "hello")
        {
            Scot.Speak("Hello sir");

            if (e.Result.Text == "how are you")
            {
                Scot.Speak("im good sir");
            }
        }
    }
```

The first if statement in their works, but then the second one won't. I can hear the voice "hello", but it won't say anything back when I say how are you. Why is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like there will be a separate SpeechRecognizedEvent every time you say something.  So, the first time you say "hello", it will hit the first if statement and say "Hello Sir" back.  However, when you say "How are you" a completely new event will be fired, meaning that when it hits the first if statement, e.Result.Text is equal to "how are you", therefor failing and not responding at all.

e.Result.Text will never change inside that event handler method - that's not how C# events work.  If you really want to have nested if statements, you could set up a flag system:

```
bool helloFlag = false;
void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    //First time you say something
    if (e.Result.Text == "hello")
    {
        Scot.Speak("Hello sir");
        helloFlag = true;
    }

    //Second time you say something
    if ( ( helloFlag == true ) && (e.Result.Text == "how are you") )
    {
        Scot.Speak("im good sir");
    }
}
```

Of course, if you're looking for a scalable solution, you'll probably want something more robust. Good luck with your AI!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so TheBlueRage was mostly correct!

```
        bool helloflag = false;
    void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result.Text == "hello")
        {
            Scot.Speak("Hello sir");
            helloflag = true;
        }

        if ((helloflag == true ) && (e.Result.Text == "how are you"))
        {
            Scot.Speak("im good sir");
            helloflag = false;
        }
    }
```

There was just a small variable that I created helloflag, so therefore it would be required to say one thing to fire off the 2nd possible response! Then after the second response it would end,also it wont get stuck in the if statement!

Answer (score 0):

I would save the word what the user said before instead of using a boolean, because you may want to add more than "Hello" --> "im good sir"

```
private static int count = 0;

void _recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
    if(count == 0)
    {
        getSet.wordBefore = e.Result.Text;
        count = 1;
    }
    else
    {
       count = 0




        if (e.Result.Text == "hello")
        {
            Scot.Speak("Hello sir");

        }

        if ((getSet.wordBefore == "Hello") && (e.Result.Text == "how are you"))
        {
            Scot.Speak("im good sir");

        }
    }
}

public static class getSet
{
    #region wordbefore

    private static string _WordBefore;
    public static string wordBefore
    {
        get {return _WordBefore;}
        set { _WordBefore = value;}
    }
    #endregion

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the way "case" commands and "if" statements connect is this:

Say you had something like this (excluding the initial addition of "good morning" in your command list):

```
switch (e.Result.Text)
{
    case "Good morning":
        Scot.Speak("Morning, Jeffrey! How are you today?");
        if(e.Result.Text == "Terrible, absolutely terrible")
        {
            Scot.Speak("Oh, I hope you feel better sir");
        }
        break;           
}
```

Your "Terrible, absolutely terrible" command will not register. TO FIX THIS, you would write out something like this:

```
public static int check1 = 0; //these "checks" are global variables
public static int check2 = 0;

switch (e.Result.Text)
{
    case "Terrible, absolutely terrible":
        if(check2 == 0)
        {
            Scot.Speak("What are you talking about?");
        }   
        break;
    case "Good morning":
        Scot.Speak("Morning, Jeffrey! How are you today?");
        //if(e.Result.Text == "Terrible, absolutely terrible")
        //{
            //Scot.Speak("Oh, I hope you feel better sir");
        //}
        check1++;
        check2++; 
        break;           
}

if(e.Result.Text == "Terrible, absolutely terrible")
{
    if(check1 == 1)
    {
        if(check2 == 1)
        {
            Scot.Speak("Oh, I hope you feel better sir");
            check1--;
        }
        check2--;
    }
}
```

Now, let me explain this process:

1) You removed the original "if" block from the "case" block of code.

2) You created a separate "if" block for your response ("Terrible, abs...").

3) You added the "check1" and "check2" as "gates"; What I mean is, you added "check1" to allow your separated "if" statement("if(e.Result...") to give clearance into the second "gate".

4) The "check2" gate is optional, but it basically makes "Terrible, abso..." available to use *in* context (the "Good morning" sequence), and *out* of context(the "case 'Terrible...':). I just put the "check2" to show how 1 command can be split into two *context-based* commands.

5) Once you've opened both "gates", you just need to reset the "check1" and "check2" variables to reset or "re-close" the gates and make the "Terrible, abs..." command available to use again.

Hope this helps you and anyone else.